# Play Youtube video in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I want to run a vide from youtube into my iPhone simulator and the URL of the vide is this

http://www.youtube.com/v/zL0CCsdS1cE

but i am not able to load this video into my iPhone, i am using a webview to display this video and here's the code to do that

```
objwebView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tempString]];
[objwebView loadRequest:request];
```

based upon the answer i tried the below code and here's a new version of my code

```
mywebView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

NSString *youTubeURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/v/zL0CCsdS1cE";

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body style=\"margin:0;background-color:#222222;\"><div style=\"padding:%i;width:%i;height:%i;background-color:#ffffff;\"><video width=\"%i\" height=\"%i\" controls=\"\" autoplay=\"\" tabindex=\"0\"><source src=\"%@\"></source></video></div></body>",10, (int)(self.view.bounds.size.width), (int)(self.view.bounds.size.height), 320, 480,youTubeURL];

[mywebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:mywebView];
```

But still i cant get the video to play

plz help

Comment: all i can see is a white view thats all nothing else

Comment: You need to create valid html that will play a video, i.e. use a <video>-tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this reference](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#YouTube), just padding the link as an `NSURL` to `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myLink]` should open the youtube app to the specified video.

Note that the simulator doesn't have the iPhone app, so this might only work on the device.

Comment: but as far as using UIApplication goes i feel that after using this code u will not have control over ur app. Also i got a message which says that safari cannot dwld this video

Comment: It switches to the youtube app. You probably got that message in the simulator; you should test this on the device.

Comment: word; you might also want to try accepting more answers on SO, people are much more eager to help those with high acceptance percentages.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it is very convenient to just load an HTML string. Basically like this (replace the variables according to your needs, and fill in the url of the video that youtube loads when displaying video as .mp4):

```
      NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"<body style=\"margin:0;background-color:#222222;\">
    <div style=\"padding:%i;width:%i;height:%i;background-color:#ffffff;\">
        <video width=\"%i\" height=\"%i\" controls=\"\" autoplay=\"\" tabindex=\"0\">
    <source src=\"%@\"></source>
        </video>
    </div>
    </body>",
     (int)margin, 
(int)(self.frame.size.width), 
(int)(self.frame.size.height), 
(int)videoWidth, 
(int)videoHeight, 
aURL];
        [objwebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

You can find the URL using Charles Debugging Proxy or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

hey use iframe and it will play video in simulator and device both..implement it like this:

```
NSString *newHTML = @"<html>\
<style>body{padding:0;margin:0;}</style>\
<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"390\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/zL0CCsdS1cE\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
</html>";
[mywebView loadHTMLString:newHTML baseURL:nil];
```